# add independent validators to controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have an ASP.NET, with a few controls on it.
Specifically, I added a `required field validator` on a textbox on the page (the text box has a `submit` button).

I then added another `required field validator` on a (different) textbox in an `Edit Item Template` of a `listview`.

The problem is that with both validators on the page, I can't posback without *both* of the controls being valid. However, these controls belong to different parts of the page and I want each one to be validated individually. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ValidationGroup` for different groups of fields.

This property will allows you to validate only fields that need to be validated for specific Postback.

So basically add `ValidationGroup` attribute to your validators and to your buttons:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator validationgroup="Group1" ... />
<asp:Button validationgroup="Group1" .../>
```

More ditails on MSDN: [**ValidationGroup Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Enabled` property of a validator, so only enable the one you want to be active at any given time.

Comment: How? the controls appear when the page loads, I can't enable or disable a control in advance (that is, not knowing which one the user will need to use).

Comment: Well, you haven't said much about the design; for instance, if your user process involved a series of postbacks for your different parts of the page you mentioned, this approach could solve your problem.